# Can I test a Windows Phone app on my Windows RT device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-rt

Developing a windows phone app with Xna using VS 2012 express.

At my progression point, I'd like to try my app, but I don't have a Windows Phone device. I have a Windows RT device but this one is not connected to my computer so I can't add it as testing device (instead of the emulator). My computer and tablet are on the same network.
Anyone know how I can generate my app and install it on the tablet?

Answer (score 1):

They are two completely different architectures, you can't run windows Phone 7/8 apps on a Win RT tablet. You will need to test a wp7/8 app on either the device emulator on your computer or on an actual windows phone 8 device.

If you need a load device, reach out to Nokia and they might be able to help, see [DVLUP load program](http://www.dvlup.com/loan#)

Alternatively, you can just purchase a Lumia 520 for very cheap off contract for testing. it's a worthy investment to make if you are serious about developing for the platform.

Comment: @Gabson There is no XNA support on WinRT. One option would be to look at MonoGame.

Comment: Ok, i may convert my xna project to monogame once i have finish. But actually i should have go for monogames from the start.

Comment: @Gabson Yes, that would be a good idea as XNA has been depreciated by Microsoft.

Comment: yes @NeilTurner but its still the only framework (with monogames) to develop games on windows phone ?

Comment: @Gabson Unity is the other popular framework that's used, but it's for WP8 and above (no WP7 support). All supports all the other major platforms too.